# select from multiple tables and sum vs join and sum

Tags: sql, mysqli

I am doing internship in an advertising company, i already implemented a tool to gather all the necessary data form facebook and import them on a database.

Now i am trying to manipulate that data, first by making some test cases and getting some results. The tables grow by 35k rows per day so after a month of using the tool i noticed that  the query i use to get the sum of certain adcreatives clicks is starting to slow down.

i am asking if the query i use can speed up if i use it with a join and how.

here is the query i have for the sum of clicks per adcreative (with adgroup_id,campaign_id as connect to the other tables):

```
<!-- language-all: lang-sql -->
SELECT t1.adgroup_id, t1.campaign_id, t1.creative_ids, SUM( t2.clicks ) AS clicks
FROM adgroups t1, adgroup_stats t2
WHERE t1.adgroup_id = t2.adgroup_id
GROUP BY t1.creative_ids
ORDER BY clicks DESC
```

currently the query takes 3 secs to complete on a dedicated server, i guess after 6 months it will be at more than 60 secs or so as the tables grow.

edit: here is the explain of the query ( although this is the first time i actually use it and not so sure what it means)

```
id  select_type table   type    possible_keys   key key_len ref rows    Extra
1   SIMPLE  t2  ALL PRIMARY NULL    NULL    NULL    671549  Using temporary; Using filesort
1   SIMPLE  t1  ref PRIMARY PRIMARY 8   fbads.t2.adgroup_id 358 Using index
```

Comment: **First of all** you need to run your join and see it's performance without any aggregations. Did you run EXPLAIN your query? Without an explain no SQL performance question should be accepted. Only when you make your join works fast - then you can go for aggregations

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That looks like a full table scan, and with that rapid growth small performance changes won't make a big difference on the long run. You need a different approach.

I would calculate aggregates for the previous months (days, etc) with a cron job, and when you need stats then merge that with the fresh results (using the query you already wrote). That why you only have to scan the fresh record, which means the queries is going to be fast.

Alternatively, you can keep up-to-date counters in the adgroups table, and update them on each click. Not sure if mysql is the right tool for this, I can recommend MongoDB, it can do very fast atomic increments on fields, and though it doesn't give you as strict guarantees (ACID) as a relational database, in this case it's not a problem, ad clicks aren't mission critical data, nobody is going to complain, if you lose < 0.01% percent of click information.

Comment: yes discrepancies call and will occur often and it is expected; even a 5% one could be acceptable if the source is somewhat pinned down. Your approach seems to make allot of sense, but the daily statistics need to stay together in this monstrosity for reasons i cannot disclose. I can however start implementing  something like that while keeping the data as i was initially asked.